# Show No record message for search on textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a `textbox` which I use for filtering `gridview`. IT filters properly whenever I add proper text. But when I dont add proper text what I want is to show some alert as, `Invalid Record`.

Below is my code

```
$(function () {
        $('.field-style').each(function (i) {
            $(this).quicksearch("[id*=grdSapDetails] tr:not(:has(th))", {
                'testQuery': function (query, txt, row) {
                    return $(row).children(":eq(" + i + ")").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query[0].toLowerCase()) != -1;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Please suggest what to do

**UPDATE**

I have added my alert message in `noResults` like below in `quicksearch.js` but still it is not giving alert.

```
 var timeout, cache, rowcache, jq_results, val = '', e = this, options = $.extend({
        delay: 100,
        selector: null,
        stripeRows: null,
        loader: null,
        noResults: 'tr#noresults',
        matchedResultsCount: 0,
        bind: 'keyup',
        onBefore: function () {
            return;
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Jquery to search the Grid View and based on the Row Filter count you can show the alert message:

```
function SearchGrid(txtSearchSAP, grdSapDetails) {

            if ($("[id *=" + txtSearchSAP + " ]").val() != "") {
            var count = 0;
                $("[id *=" + grdSapDetails + " ]").children
                ('tbody').children('tr').each(function () {
                    $(this).show();
                });
                $("[id *=" + grdSapDetails + " ]").children
                ('tbody').children('tr').each(function () {
                    var match = false;
                    $(this).children('td').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf($("[id *=" +
                    txtSearchSAP + " ]").val().toUpperCase()) > -1) {
                            match = true;
                            count++;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    if (match) {

                        $(this).show();
                        $(this).children('th').show();
                    }
                    else {

                        $(this).hide();
                        $(this).children('th').show();

                    }
                });


                $("[id *=" + grdSapDetails + " ]").children('tbody').
                        children('tr').each(function (index) {

                            if (index == 0)
                            {
                               $(this).show();
                            }



                        });

                        if(count==0)
                        {
                        alert("No Matching Records");
                        }
            }
            else {
                $("[id *=" + grdSapDetails + " ]").children('tbody').
                        children('tr').each(function () {
                            $(this).show();
                            count=0;
                        });
                }
        }

        $(document).on("keyup", function () {                        
            SearchGrid('txtSearchSAP', 'grdSapDetails');
        });
```

Here is the [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/py1s28e5/)

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand how are you merging server side and client side code.
You are talking about server control (GridView) so you can use the `EmptyDataText` property.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatext(v=vs.110).aspx

Client side you can work on document ready: counting visible rows and showing a message.

Comment: I want to show client side error message. and NOt on server side.. do let me know how to implement that

Comment: quicksearch plugin has `'noResults': 'tr#noresults'` property. https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch

Comment: I am adding like this `noResults: 'Please enter valid Record',` but it is not showing the message while adding invalid record. why ?

Comment: Missing apex 'noResults'? Can you edit your first post showing the code?

Comment: And have you got a tr in html with id = noresults?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141566/discussion-between-vvvv-and-emanuele).